# How to SUM based on criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My CSV sample data is

```
ID,Project,From,To,Percentage
1,APPLE,01-01-2022,31-03-2022,50
1,MICROSOFT,01-01-2022,15-01-2022,50
1,MICROSOFT,01-02-2022,28-02-2022,50
1,MICROSOFT,01-03-2022,31-03-2022,50
2,ORACLE,01-02-2022,23-06-2022,50
3,APPLE,23-04-2022,23-06-2022,100
1,MICROSOFT,16-01-2022,31-01-2022,50
2,DELL,01-12-2021,01-04-2022,50
```

[image]

My objective is to see if on any date any employee has been allocated for more than 100% in a project. As you can see employee id 1 has been allocated 1/Jan/22 to 31/Mar/22 for 50% in APPLE and multiple sub-periods in MICROSOFT for 50% itself but it isn't for any period greater than 100% allocation.

How when I sum(percentage) using this criteria `(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)`

I get 250% for the first line item because it will match with all other line times for ID=1. The period is engulfing all the smaller periods.

Is there a way to check if any employee has been allocated for more than 100% on any given date?

Edit: EXPECTED RESULT
[image]

Comment: show the expected result on the given data, not everything is clear.

Comment: responded. See both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is your expect result given your data would be rather lame. So I added one more line:

```
  ID    Project       From         To Percentage
0  1      APPLE 2022-01-01 2022-03-31         50
1  1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-01 2022-01-15         50
2  1  MICROSOFT 2022-02-01 2022-02-28         50
3  1  MICROSOFT 2022-03-01 2022-03-31         50
4  2     ORACLE 2022-02-01 2022-06-23         50
5  3      APPLE 2022-04-23 2022-06-23        100
6  1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-16 2022-01-31         50
7  2       DELL 2021-12-01 2022-04-01         50
0  1       Home 2022-01-01 2022-01-07         75
```

Doing:

```
# Format dates as proper datetimes.
df['From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['From'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['To'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

# Create the date Range:
df['dates'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row.From, row.To, freq='D'), axis=1)

# Explode the dates:
df = df.explode('dates')

# Find the dates where someone is over allocated:
out = df.groupby(['ID', 'dates'])['Percentage'].sum()[lambda x: x.gt(100)]
print(out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID      dates Percentage
0   1 2022-01-01        175
1   1 2022-01-02        175
2   1 2022-01-03        175
3   1 2022-01-04        175
4   1 2022-01-05        175
5   1 2022-01-06        175
6   1 2022-01-07        175
```

---

To put it back into your original data format:

```
df['allocation'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'dates'])['Percentage'].transform('sum')
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Project', 'From', 'To', 'Percentage'], as_index=False)['allocation'].max()
```

Output:

```
   ID    Project       From         To  Percentage  allocation
0   1      APPLE 2022-01-01 2022-03-31          50         175
1   1       Home 2022-01-01 2022-01-07          75         175
2   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-01 2022-01-15          50         175
3   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-16 2022-01-31          50         100
4   1  MICROSOFT 2022-02-01 2022-02-28          50         100
5   1  MICROSOFT 2022-03-01 2022-03-31          50         100
6   2       DELL 2021-12-01 2022-04-01          50         100
7   2     ORACLE 2022-02-01 2022-06-23          50         100
8   3      APPLE 2022-04-23 2022-06-23         100         100
```

---

Since there appears to be some confusion about how this works, here's a poor visualization of the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(16,6))

for group in df.groupby('ID'):
    temp_df = group[1]
    ax.barh(y=temp_df.Project, width=temp_df.days_start_to_end, left=temp_df.start_num, label=temp_df.ID.unique())

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Gantt Chart]

This doesn't properly show per-project percentages, but it does show that at certain time periods ID 1 has been assigned to three different projects. In this case we've calculated that from 1/1 to 1/7 they're overbooked at 175%. The original formatting of the table is unable to show this, so the best we can do is display the max utilization during the given row's time period.

Comment: fyi - could handle the dates on the way in from the CSV:  `pd.read_csv(..., dayfirst=True, parse_dates=['From','To'])`

Comment: well given your logic, the date range of the first row captures the data of four more rows. And this is 250 and not 175.

Comment: @inquirer I added a visualization of my logic. The max utilization during those time periods is `175%` in this case, `50+50+75 = 175`. Just because APPLE and Home overlap, doesn't mean that Home should be added to every MICROSOFT value... just the first one.

Comment: @BeRT2me excellent and detaied solution. Accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

There may be no simple one-line code to do your task. However, it can be handled through some for loop and conditions as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'id': 'ali', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-15'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-17'),'Percentage':50},
        {'id': 'ali', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-18'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-22'),'Percentage':50},
        {'id': 'ali', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-20'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-25'),'Percentage':50},
        {'id': 'sadegh', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-15'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-17'), 'Percentage': 50},
        {'id': 'sadegh', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-18'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-22'), 'Percentage': 50},
        {'id': 'sadegh', 'from': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-20'), 'to': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-25'), 'Percentage': 50}
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


dic = {}
unique_times = np.unique(df['to'].to_list() + df['from'].to_list())
list = []
for i in df.id.unique():
    for count in range(unique_times.__len__()-1):
          condition_1 = df[df.id==i]['from'] <= unique_times[count]
          condition_2 = df[df.id==i]['to'] >= unique_times[count+1]
          dic['{}_{}'.format(unique_times[count], unique_times[count+1])] = np.sum(df[df.id == i]['Percentage'][condition_1 & condition_2])
    list.append(dic)

Data_frame = pd.DataFrame(list,index=df.id.unique())
```

In this code for each id, the percentage for each possible time interval is calculated and saved in a data frame. After that, You can simply determine if there is an interval of time for which the contribution percentage is higher than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate sum of percentage allocation by ID by individual date.  Then take the max of each day by ID. In other words, sums the percentage on a day-by-day basis by ID then takes the max value over all the days:

```
pd.concat([df[['ID','Project','From','To']],df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Percentage'], index=pd.date_range(start=x['From'], end=x['To'])), axis=1)], axis=1) \
    .groupby('ID').sum().max(axis=1)

ID
1    100.0
2    100.0
3    100.0
```

**An example with a smaller set of date ranges**

```
   ID    Project       From         To  Percentage
0   1      APPLE 2022-01-01 2022-01-03          50
1   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-01 2022-01-05          50
2   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-02 2022-01-06          50
3   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-06 2022-01-08          50
4   2     ORACLE 2022-01-01 2022-01-04          50
5   3      APPLE 2022-01-06 2022-01-08         100
6   1  MICROSOFT 2022-01-05 2022-01-08          50
7   2       DELL 2022-01-05 2022-01-08          50

pd.concat([df[['ID','Project','From','To']],df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Percentage'], index=pd.date_range(start=x['From'], end=x['To'])), axis=1)], axis=1) \
    .groupby('ID').sum().max(axis=1)

ID
1    150.0
2     50.0
3    100.0
```

Answer (score -1):

where the employee is not 100% involved, will be NaN.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

aaa = df.groupby('ID').sum().reset_index()
mask = aaa[aaa['Percentage'] >= 100]
df.loc[np.isin(df['ID'], mask['ID']), 'expected result'] = 100
print(df)
```

Or you can do it easier and better. Take all the sums by ID, compare with the number 100 and get these indices. Assign 100 where the condition is met, and leave the remaining amounts as they are.

```
fff = df.groupby('ID')['Percentage'].transform('sum')
mask = fff.ge(100)
fff[mask] = 100
df['expected result'] = fff
print(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual dates at all?

Comment: I quote:"Is there a way to check if any employee has been allocated for more than 100% on any given date". Given the expected result, is it possible that all the data is meant? Or do need to get specifically by the specified date from and to for each user, then it doesn't match the expected result.

Comment: My answer does match the expected result given the input data from OP.